# Restart ReduceByKeyAndWindows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

i am really new on Spark and Scala, and i am using **ReduceByKeyAndWindows** to count words in kafka messages, because i need use window functionality.

the purpose of my aplication is sent an alert when detects "x" times messages from kafka that containts a specific word in a specific time. then, restart from the begin.

The code below detect the word but i can´t make that my aplication restart again. i am thinking if possible restart the accumulation of ReduceByKeyAndWindows or other way to do this.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._ // not necessary since Spark 1.3

object KafKaWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("KafKaWordCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2))

    ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999) //using NETCAT for test 
    val wordCounts = 
        lines.map(x => (x, 1))
             .reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Seconds(60), Seconds(2), 2) 

        //if the value from the key (word) exceeds 10 , sent alert and Restart the values
        wordCounts.print()
        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

---

Using the second example from  **Yuval Itzchakov** 
and reducing the number of reach from 10 to 3 and sending 7 messages.

The output from the second asnwer is

```
Word: hello reached count: 1
Word: hello reached count: 2
//No print this message, its OK but the next word not start with 1
Word: hello reached count: 4
Word: hello reached count: 5
Word: hello reached count: 6
Word: hello reached count: 7
```

The output that i expect

```
Word: hello reached count: 1
Word: hello reached count: 2

Word: hello reached count: 1
Word: hello reached count: 2

Word: hello reached count: 1
```

Comment: It is a little bit hard to understand what you want but I get this impression that you actually need some more general function like `updateStateByKey`.

Comment: thank you, i will read about this,
You can show me an example how i can use the function? supose that i recibe this:
 ** hello ** 
i will accumulate this
 **(hello , 1)**  
 **(hello , 2)** 
 **(hello , 3)**
And when, **hello** exceeds ** 5 ** i will send the alert and **hello** needs to be **0** and start again..
Sorry, i am new in this page too. Thanks Again!

Comment: Not that pretty example nevertheless: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35565682/1560062

Comment: Hi again, i  tried updateStateByKey but doesnt have the functionality window . No way to force a restart of window ? to start accumulating from 0 again? :(

Comment: What do you mean by "restart the window"? Do you only mean start counting again? Or reading from the beginning of the stream?

Comment: hi @YuvalItzchakov Start Counting Again. can you help me?

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using?

Comment: the version is 1.4.1

Comment: See my bottom answer which uses `updateStateByKey`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spark 1.6.0 and above, you can use the experimental `DStream.mapWithState` to keep the updated state of your word count. Once it reaches the limit, you can remove the state and release it to the pipeline, and print it out with `DStream.foreach`:

```
object KafKaWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[2]")
    .setAppName("KafKaWordCount")

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2))
    ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999) //using NETCAT for test
    val stateSpec = StateSpec.function(updateWordCount _)

    lines.map(x => (x, 1))
      .reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, _ - _, Seconds(60), Seconds(2), 2)
      .mapWithState(stateSpec)
      .filter(_.isDefined)
      .foreachRDD(rdd => 
                  rdd.foreach { case (word, count) => 
                    println(s"Word: $word reached count: $count") })
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

  def updateWordCount(key: String, 
                      value: Option[Int], 
                      state: State[(String, Int)]): Option[(String, Int)] = {
    def updateCountState(count: Int): Option[(String, Int)] = {
      if (count == 10) {
        if (state.exists()) state.remove()
        Some((key, count))
      }
      else {
        state.update((key, count))
        None
      }
    }

    value match {
      case Some(count) => updateCountState(count)
      case _ => None
    }
  }
}
```

If not, you can defer to the slower `DStream.updateStateByKey`:

```
object KafKaWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[2]")
    .setAppName("KafKaWordCount")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2))

    ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")

    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999) //using NETCAT for test

    lines.map(x => (x, (x, 1)))
         .reduceByKeyAndWindow((first: (String, Int), second: (String, Int)) =>
                               (first._1, first._2 + second._2), Seconds(60), Seconds(60), 2)
         .updateStateByKey(updateSeqCount _)
         .print(1)

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

  def updateSeqCount(values: Seq[(String, Int)], 
                     state: Option[(String, Int]): Option[(String, Int)] = {
        if (values.isEmpty) state
        else {
          val (word, count) = values.head  
          if (count == 10) {
            println(s"Key: $word reached count $count!")
            None 
          }
          else Some((word, count))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u, I will try it

Comment: How use StateSpec? i want reproduce your example, i am missing some import?
Really sorry for my questions! I am really new with spark.

Comment: See the buttom example with `updateStateByKey`, not the upper one. `StateSpec` is for 1.6.0

Comment: the application does not print when the word reach to 10, its good!. but the count doesnt return to 0, just go ahead. i am missing something? thank you

Comment: Are there more words streaming in? What does your output look like

Comment: no, just the same word. i edit your example, and i add the output expected.

Comment: @Gabriel Updated my code. Forgot update state works a little differently

Comment: The code have syntax error, i can´t fix it. 
please help me

Comment: now the code don´t print nothing, :( , this works for you?