# Spark streaming: Cache DStream results across batches

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

Using Spark streaming (1.6) I have a filestream for reading lookup data with 2s of batch size, however files are copyied to the directory only every hour.
Once there's a new file, its content is read by the stream, this is what I want to cache into memory and keep there
until new files are read. 
There's another stream to which I want to join this dataset therefore I'd like to cache.

This is a follow-up question of [Batch lookup data for Spark streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37447393/batch-lookup-data-for-spark-streaming).
The answer does work fine with `updateStateByKey` however I don't know how to deal with cases when a KV pair is 
*deleted* from the lookup files, as the Sequence of values in `updateStateByKey` keeps growing.
Also any hint how to do this with `mapWithState` would be great.

This is what I tried so far, but the data doesn't seem to be persisted:

```
val dictionaryStream = ssc.textFileStream("/my/dir")
dictionaryStream.foreachRDD{x => 
  if (!x.partitions.isEmpty) {
    x.unpersist(true)
    x.persist()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`DStreams` can be persisted directly using `persist` method which persist every RDD in the stream:

```
dictionaryStream.persist
```

According to [the official documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#caching--persistence) this applied automatically for

> window-based operations like `reduceByWindow` and `reduceByKeyAndWindow` and state-based operations like `updateStateByKey`

so there should be no need for explicit caching in your case. Also there is no need for manual unpersisting. To quote [the docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37550054/spark-streaming-cache-dstream-results-across-batches) once again:

> by default, all input data and persisted RDDs generated by DStream transformations are automatically cleared

and a retention period is tuned automatically based on the transformations which are used in the pipeline.

Regarding `mapWithState` you'll have to provide  a `StateSpec`. A minimal example requires a functions which takes `key`, `Option` of current `value` and previous state. Lets say you have `DStream[(String, Long)]` and you want to record maximum value so far:

```
val state = StateSpec.function(
  (key: String, current: Option[Double], state: State[Double]) => {
    val max  = Math.max(
      current.getOrElse(Double.MinValue),
      state.getOption.getOrElse(Double.MinValue)
    )
    state.update(max)
    (key, max)
  }
)

val inputStream: DStream[(String, Double)] = ??? 
inputStream.mapWithState(state).print()
```

It is also possible to provide initial state, timeout interval and capture current batch time. The last two can be used to implement removal strategy for the keys which haven't been update for some period of time.

Comment: Thanks again! I only want to achieve that once a `fileStream` has received some data, cache it and use it till the next time it will receive something. With persist I couldn't achieve this. If I put `current.headOption.orElse(prev)` in `updateStateByKey` as you suggested in the previous question, then it will cache the element but I won't be able to tell whether `current` is null because at the given batch no new data was read by `fileStream` or it's null because the value was in the meanwhile deleted.

Comment: `persist` / `unpersist` doesn't affect the data you see. It is only a performance hint. Just because you `unpersist` data you observe __won't__ change. `timeout` in `mapWithState` can be used to forget the state but is slightly awkward.

Comment: Thank you, I see. My other idea for this problem is to somehow periodically broadcast the filestream data and do lookups from the mainStream. However I don't know what happens in the interval when the new data is (re)broadcasted to the worker nodes in terms of consistency. What would you suggest me for this problem?

Comment: I don't it is a good choice. The only way I can think of to make it possible is to do it in a relatively  reliable way is to use `transform` / `foreachRDD` closure and rebroadcast on every batch. And it still doesn't provide determinism in case of recovery.

Comment: You could also try to pass things using file system and access data via objects which will take care of updating in a way slightly similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37343437/1560062).

Comment: Thanks for all your support. I finally created a custom ´InputDStream´ based on ´ConstantInputDStream´ which reads the latest file from an HDFS dir, caches the RDD and returns this RDD for the subsequent calls from compute() until there's a change on HDFS. Local tests seems to be fine so far.