# Spark Streaming with Scala: is there a way which i can postpone dealing with data to next batch

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am working with Spark-Streaming + Scala, and i have the following scenario:

I need to create a Funnel (which is defined by page-views and clicks).
A click must be connected to a page-view occurred before the click.

The problem might occur, when i get the click event in the batch before, the batch which i get the page-view event.

Is there a way which i can postpone the click event to the next event, and
try to deal with it then ?
Also a TTL is needed in such case, so we can throw the event after several batches.

thanks,
Eran.

Comment: Use stateful transformations like [`mapWithState`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37550054/1560062) or  `updateStateByKey`?

Comment: i will try it. thanks !